# Two different editor in one content typ

Tags: 8, paragraphs

is there a way in drupal 8 to use two different editors (CKeditor with two different buttonpanels or two differently allowed html tags) in one content type?

I have created a content type of a text field (body) and with the module paragraph other text fields are created. the user should use the possibilities in the body field of pictures and tables but in the text fields of paragraph the user should not be allowed to do so.

I have now created two different editors but the user can always switch between the editors. How can I determine that only one editor can be used in the body field and only the other one in the remaining text fields?
many thanks for your help!
s-webz

Comment: Use Better Formats module to limit format options regardless of the current user permission.

Comment: this is not a option becouse it is a production sites :-( but big thx

Comment: I don't know what that means. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the module https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats.

> Limit which text formats are available for each field instance.

Comment: Nice! The module does exactly what I was looking for! big thank you.